# Why are discrete random measures not dominated?

Tags: dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

A statement I’ve seen without proof in many books and papers is that random probability measures obtained by normalizing a completely random measure, such as the Dirichlet process, are not dominated by a common $\sigma$-finite measure and therefore the posterior can’t be obtained using Bayes theorem. I can intuitively grasp why is that but don’t know how to prove it.

Comment: Have a look at section 7.6 in these really good lecture notes: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~porbanz/papers/porbanz_BNP_draft.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwimw4GIv6_qAhVk7aYKHZuYBDIQFjACegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3_54xl5J5iK50nnPQxyhlE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elaborating on my comment, I think an example can be shown for basically every mixture model.

Suppose you have a Normalized Random Measure of the form
$$
  P(\cdot) = \sum_h w_h \delta_{\phi_h}(\cdot)
$$
with the usual condition that the weights sum to $1$ and that $\phi_h$ are i.i.d from a non-atomic distribution (non atomicity is important)

Now suppose that you observe a single datum $X_1 = x^*$, living in a Polish space $(\mathbb X, \mathcal X)$.
$$X_1 \mid P \sim P \quad P \sim \Pi$$
with $\Pi$ a measure on $\mathbb P_X$ the space of all probability measures on $(\mathbb X, \mathcal X)$.

Since the $\phi_h$s come from a diffuse measure, this entails that the set $A = \{\text{random measures that have an atom in $x^*$}\} \subset \mathbb P_X$ will have $0$ prior mass, i.e. $\Pi(A) = 0$.

On the other hand, we know that if $\Pi$ is for example a Dirichlet process,
$\Pi(A \mid X_1 = x^*) = 1$.

So that the prior does not dominate the posterior, thus Bayes' theorem does not hold and the model cannot be dominated.